# Best way to provide env variables (secrets) to docker compose that spins up containers on EC2 auto-scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, aws-auto-scaling

I need to launch a set of Docker containers on an EC2 instance using docker compose. The EC2 instances are part of an auto-scaling group, and the compose command is executed as part of the `user-data` script that runs on instance start up.

As part of the `user-data` script, I need to do two things:

- Provide the `docker-compose.yaml` file to the instance. I plan to place the file into an S3 bucket and download it. (If there is a better way, let me know.)
- Provide env variables, required by the `docker-compose.yaml`, to the instance. How do I securely do this? The env variables include secrets like database credentials.

I read docker compose env [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/), so the possible solutions seem to be:

1. Hard-code env variables in the `docker-compose.yaml` file using the `environment` attribute. Is that safe?
2. Place the variables into their own `env_file`, and put them on S3 too. That's basically the same as #1. (But allows us to maintain separate env configurations.)
3. Provide the variables as part of the shell environment.

I am hoping there is a way to do #3 using some sort of managed secret service on AWS?

My requirements are:

- I do not want to hard code the secrets in any file, ever. I don't want a file with company secrets sitting on S3.
- Ideally, managing secrets is done as part of an automated terraform pipeline, so I don't have to manually copy/paste them around.

  - Example: Every time I spin up the infrastructure, I want the secrets to be automatically generated by terraform and saved somewhere secure, where EC2 can access them. Every time I tear down, I want the secrets to be wiped.

Am I overthinking this? How do people normally do this? I assume this is a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a clear example that fits my requirements.

Comment: It sounds like you are reinventing AWS ECS. I would recommend looking at ECS before going any further. If you continue to use docker-compose via user-data, I would store the secrets in AWS Parameter Store, or Secrets Manager, and have your user-data script load those via AWS API calls when the EC2 instance starts up.

Comment: @MarkB I may be reinventing ECS. I will look into it. The main reason we are using low-level user-data is because we need to heavily modify the EC2 instance after launch. Can I combine ECS with a custom-templated auto-scaling groups?

Comment: Yes you can customize the auto-scaling group that ECS users for the underlying EC2 instances. As to your question about "how do people normally do this" the normal way to provide secrets to something you are running via user-data is to have the user-data script call out to Parameter Store or Secrets Manager to load secrets.

Comment: @MarkB Could you please submit this as an answer, so I can mark the question as complete. (One additional wrinkle here, I think, is making sure the EC2 has the role that allows it to interact with the Secrets Manager).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest looking into ECS instead of inventing your own docker container orchestration system for EC2. However, to answer the basic question:

> How do people normally do this? I assume this is a common problem, but I haven't been able to find a clear example that fits my requirements.

The normal way to provide secrets to something you are running via `user-data` is to have the `user-data` script call out to AWS Parameter Store, or AWS Secrets Manager to load secrets. The `user-data` script would use the AWS CLI tool to make those calls. The IAM Instance Profile assigned to the EC2 instance would need to give the appropriate permissions to access the secret(s) in Parameter Store or Secretes Manager, as well as the appropriate permissions to decrypt the secrets if you are using a KMS CMK to encrypt them.